# What are ways to create custom LabVIEW controls?

Tags: html, silverlight, qt, webgl, labview

I'm looking for a robust and efficient method of creating any kind of imaginable control to use with a LabVIEW project. I'm curious what you've tried and what the pros and cons are. I myself have never used LabVIEW, but have been approached to write controls for it based on my knowledge of other things (C#, HTML5, Flash, Silverlight, etc).

It appears to me as though this kind of thing has been or can be done in .NET, Flash, WebGL, Qt, Silverlight, and maybe some others as well. Ideally, we don't want to have to write any code twice, so platform flexibility is a great thing, which makes me lean toward a web solution. But ease of implementation is important as well, and I would think a web solution would require some extensive web services parsing and programming every time a control is going to be used. But I could be wrong. An eye on the future is also important. If something would be a great solution today, but probably worthless in 2 years, no point in bringing it up.

(Please realize that I am NOT simply asking how to change the colors of (customize) a LabVIEW control, nor am I interested in xControls as the final solution as apparently they aren't robust enough.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this probably doesn't answer your question, but if you have access to LabVIEW, you could analyse the ["Military" Theme Custom Control Suite](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-6325), and look at examples on the [UI Interest Group](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/ui) and [LabVIEW UI Tips and Tricks](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/ui/blog/2010/04/29/creating-quality-uis-with-ni-labview--developer-days-2010-presentation). That's probably the best you could do with LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0):

.NET is probably your best bet, LabVIEW supports .net controls, so you can define the UI and reuse your .net code.

I have heard rumours that the new LabVIEW version (2013 due in September) will use .NET 4 libraries as the default instead of the current 2, so you might want to keep that in mind.

I wouldn't ditch XControls that easily if I was your company (I can understand it's not your cup of tea).